# JSF- How can I create a href for a cell in datatable for opening a dialogue

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

Here is my code.Based on the value the I will open a dialogue which will retrieve the number of list.Say if the cell values is 7 when i click the 7 a dialogue will open and in the opened dialogue it will retrieve 7 rows in the datatable in the pop up.

```
 <p:commandLink value="#{row.inprogress}"
rendered="#{row.value}"
            actionListener="#{Bean.showIpdpInProgressPopup}"            update=":somefield"
            style="display:block;background-color:#{row.backgroundcolor}">
```

This method `showIpdpInProgressPopup` will open a dialogue from the backing bean.
I don't want to use `<p:commandLink>` to open a dialogue.Instead,what else can I use to open the dialogue ?

Comment: You can also use a p:commandButton instead of p:commandLink. On click of the button you can open a dialog. E.g <p:commandButton id="basic" value="Basic" onclick="PF('dlg1').show();" type="button" />  . The p:dialog can retrieve the data from the bean .

Comment: Thanks zee.I don't to bring a commandbutton inside the cell.A value is already there, all I have to do is to open a dialogue by clicking it like "ahref" kind of thing in HTML.I s there any other option ?

Comment: still you can have a button next to your value within the same cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was when I used  the font was always underlined and my main requirement is to remove the underline.And I came to know the fix for this is very simple which I have given below

```
<p:commandLink value="#{row.inprogress}"
                                        rendered="#{row.value}"
                                        actionListener="#{Bean.showIpdpInProgressPopup}"
                                        update=":somefield"
                                        style="text-decoration:none;color:blue;display:block;background:#{row.backgroundcolor}"/>
```

So `style="text-decoration:none;` did the thing for me.Thanks all for your valuable ideas and suggestions.Appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `overlayPanel` for opening a dialogue like below.

```
<p:commandLink id="rolSec" action="#{rolDegistirController.rolBul}" update=":kisiselBilgilerForm:rolForm:kullaniciRolForm">
    Değiştir
</p:commandLink >


<p:overlayPanel dynamic="true" for="kisiselBilgilerForm:rolSec">
    <ui:include src="include/rolDegistirForm.xhtml"/>
</p:overlayPanel>
```

When you click Değiştir link, the overlayPanel will be opened and with second click it will be closed.